# Utils package in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, frontend, chart.js, chart.js3

I'm trying reproducing this example from chart.js documentation:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/interpolation.html

But I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Utils is not defined

I tried searching for "Utils" in Chart.js documentation but with no success.
Any idea how can I use it correctly? I'm obviously missing something basic.

Comment: Hello jms-bid. I have same problem (I think). To be sure and to answer correctly to your question, can you put YOUR html file here on StackOverflow (not only a reference of what you will try) and can you document where your error occurs in your code ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @schlebe! My code was a 1:1 copy of the reference I linked, so no need to add anything else. The accepted answer below solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but HTML file on ChartJs is a full page with more than what you want to test (I think). So can you put your html code ? The fact that there exists already a solution is not enough to give a better solution ! Please, give your code or better create a Code Snipped !

Comment: ```<div id="mygraph"></div>
```

This is all the HTML man...

Comment: And what happens when chartjs page would be replaced or deleted ? No body will understand your question. This is good behavior on StackOverflow to avoid hyperlink and to take some time to write complete problem, not only using a link because it is simple for you.

Comment: And what happens when this StackOverflow page would be replaced or deleted? No body will even get to my question. Maybe for good behaviour we should write all this comments somewhere too! Just in case :D

Comment: It is not the spirit of StackOverflow. You search help for you but also for others. If you miss this concept, the only thing I can add is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMALuEYxK6U

Comment: Chart js has poor document. They use Utils class **a lot** just like one of the official class but there is no file in the released packages on GitHub.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I searched around in [Github project](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) 
Here is the [link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/scripts/utils.js) to the **Utils** file mentioned in the code samples.
Add this file to your project it should work now.

Adding the mentioned Utils code if the link gets broken in the future.

```
import colorLib from '@kurkle/color';
import {DateTime} from 'luxon';
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon';
import {valueOrDefault} from '../../dist/helpers.esm';

// Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
var _seed = Date.now();

export function srand(seed) {
  _seed = seed;
}

export function rand(min, max) {
  min = valueOrDefault(min, 0);
  max = valueOrDefault(max, 0);
  _seed = (_seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
  return min + (_seed / 233280) * (max - min);
}

export function numbers(config) {
  var cfg = config || {};
  var min = valueOrDefault(cfg.min, 0);
  var max = valueOrDefault(cfg.max, 100);
  var from = valueOrDefault(cfg.from, []);
  var count = valueOrDefault(cfg.count, 8);
  var decimals = valueOrDefault(cfg.decimals, 8);
  var continuity = valueOrDefault(cfg.continuity, 1);
  var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
  var data = [];
  var i, value;

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
    if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
      data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
    } else {
      data.push(null);
    }
  }

  return data;
}

export function points(config) {
  const xs = this.numbers(config);
  const ys = this.numbers(config);
  return xs.map((x, i) => ({x, y: ys[i]}));
}

export function bubbles(config) {
  return this.points(config).map(pt => {
    pt.r = this.rand(config.rmin, config.rmax);
    return pt;
  });
}

export function labels(config) {
  var cfg = config || {};
  var min = cfg.min || 0;
  var max = cfg.max || 100;
  var count = cfg.count || 8;
  var step = (max - min) / count;
  var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
  var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
  var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
  var values = [];
  var i;

  for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
    values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
  }

  return values;
}

const MONTHS = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];

export function months(config) {
  var cfg = config || {};
  var count = cfg.count || 12;
  var section = cfg.section;
  var values = [];
  var i, value;

  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    value = MONTHS[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
    values.push(value.substring(0, section));
  }

  return values;
}

const COLORS = [
  '#4dc9f6',
  '#f67019',
  '#f53794',
  '#537bc4',
  '#acc236',
  '#166a8f',
  '#00a950',
  '#58595b',
  '#8549ba'
];

export function color(index) {
  return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
}

export function transparentize(value, opacity) {
  var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
  return colorLib(value).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
}

export const CHART_COLORS = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

const NAMED_COLORS = [
  CHART_COLORS.red,
  CHART_COLORS.orange,
  CHART_COLORS.yellow,
  CHART_COLORS.green,
  CHART_COLORS.blue,
  CHART_COLORS.purple,
  CHART_COLORS.grey,
];

export function namedColor(index) {
  return NAMED_COLORS[index % NAMED_COLORS.length];
}

export function newDate(days) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({days}).toJSDate();
}

export function newDateString(days) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({days}).toISO();
}

export function parseISODate(str) {
  return DateTime.fromISO(str);
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing to this problem with another of their samples.

But this answer only oddly helps: as the word "Utils" doesn't appear anywhere in the file, how do the sample knows how to rely a call like "Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG)" to the "numbers" function in this file?

Also the file has its own imports. Do I have any chance to have these imports working once the file will have been copied on my computer?

Obviously there is still something missing, or maybe I am completely dumb in Javascript…

Comment: current util.j smodule is intended for react or others, not for pure JS

Comment: @GingkoFr Did you get it working?

Answer (score 12):

Current Chart util.js source code is intented for anular or react, but not for pure JS.

Use this adaptation I made, name chart.util.js , place say on your rootweb/inc/

Im using later a script code to port the Polar Area chart, butwith the chart.util.js file I made then other charts will be ok, porting the body scripts
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/polar-area.html

chart.util.js ======= ####

```
'use strict';

window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

(function(global) {
    var MONTHS = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    ];
    var COLORS = [
        '#4dc9f6',
        '#f67019',
        '#f53794',
        '#537bc4',
        '#acc236',
        '#166a8f',
        '#00a950',
        '#58595b',
        '#8549ba'
    ];
    var Samples = global.Samples || (global.Samples = {});
    var Color = global.Color;
    Samples.utils = {
        // Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
        srand: function(seed) {
            this._seed = seed;
        },

        rand: function(min, max) {
            var seed = this._seed;
            min = min === undefined ? 0 : min;
            max = max === undefined ? 1 : max;
            this._seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
            return min + (this._seed / 233280) * (max - min);
        },
        numbers: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 1;
            var from = cfg.from || [];
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var continuity = cfg.continuity || 1;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var data = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
                if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
                    data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
                } else {
                    data.push(null);
                }
            }

            return data;
        },
        labels: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 100;
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var step = (max - min) / count;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
            var values = [];
            var i;

            for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
                values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
            }

            return values;
        },
        months: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var count = cfg.count || 12;
            var section = cfg.section;
            var values = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = MONTHS[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
                values.push(value.substring(0, section));
            }

            return values;
        },
        color: function(index) {
            return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
        },

        //transparentize: function(color, opacity) {
        //  var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
        //  return ColorO(color).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
        //}
        transparentize: function (r, g, b, alpha) {
              const a = (1 - alpha) * 255;
              const calc = x => Math.round((x - a)/alpha);

              return `rgba(${calc(r)}, ${calc(g)}, ${calc(b)}, ${alpha})`;
            }
    

    };
    // DEPRECATED
    window.randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Samples.utils.rand(-100, 100));
    };
    // INITIALIZATION
    Samples.utils.srand(Date.now());

}(this));
```

then on your .html with pure JS use:
On header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yourweb.com/inc/chart.utils.js"></script>
```

then on BODY before end of body tag

```
<script>
const actions = [
  {
    name: 'Randomize',
    handler(chart) {
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
        dataset.data = Samples.utils.numbers({count: chart.data.labels.length, min: 0, max: 100});
      });
      chart.update();
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Add Data',
    handler(chart) {
      const data = chart.data;
      if (data.datasets.length > 0) {
        data.labels.push('data #' + (data.labels.length + 1));

        for (var index = 0; index < data.datasets.length; ++index) {
          data.datasets[index].data.push(Samples.utils.rand(0, 100));
        }

        chart.update();
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Remove Data',
    handler(chart) {
      chart.data.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

      chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
        dataset.data.pop();
      });

      chart.update();
    }
  }
];
const DATA_COUNT = 5;
const NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: 0, max: 100};
const labels = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: Samples.utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      backgroundColor: [
        Samples.utils.transparentize(255, 99, 132, 0.5),
        Samples.utils.transparentize(255, 159, 64, 0.5),
        Samples.utils.transparentize(255, 205, 86, 0.5),
        Samples.utils.transparentize(75, 192, 192, 0.5),
        Samples.utils.transparentize(54, 162, 235, 0.5),
      ]
    }
  ]
};
const config = {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Polar Area Chart'
      }
    }
  },
};
 var myChart = new Chart( document.getElementById('myChart'), config, data, actions );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 10):

I created a small library for quick use of samples Chart.js:
You can just take the script https://github.com/imhvost/chart-utils/blob/master/dist/chart-utils.min.js and initialize Utils:

```
const Utils = ChartUtils.init();
```

And the code from the Chart.js samples starts working:

```
const DATA_COUNT = 7
const NUMBER_CFG = { count: DATA_COUNT, min: -100, max: 100 }

const labels = Utils.months({ count: 7 })
const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Fully Rounded',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.red, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      borderSkipped: false
    },
    {
      label: 'Small Radius',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderSkipped: false
    }
  ]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

`borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red`,

I used

`borderColor: '#00FF00',` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Current utils.js is not working for pure/vanilla JS.

Use the following one instead:

```
    var _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____ = function(name) {return (self._wb_wombat && self._wb_wombat.local_init && self._wb_wombat.local_init(name)) || self[name]; };
if (!self.__WB_pmw) { self.__WB_pmw = function(obj) { this.__WB_source = obj; return this; } }
{
  let window = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("window");
  let self = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("self");
  let document = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("document");
  let location = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("location");
  let top = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("top");
  let parent = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("parent");
  let frames = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("frames");
  let opener = _____WB$wombat$assign$function_____("opener");

'use strict';

window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};

(function(global) {
    var MONTHS = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    ];

    var COLORS = [
        '#4dc9f6',
        '#f67019',
        '#f53794',
        '#537bc4',
        '#acc236',
        '#166a8f',
        '#00a950',
        '#58595b',
        '#8549ba'
    ];

    var Samples = global.Samples || (global.Samples = {});
    var Color = global.Color;

    Samples.utils = {
        // Adapted from http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/
        srand: function(seed) {
            this._seed = seed;
        },

        rand: function(min, max) {
            var seed = this._seed;
            min = min === undefined ? 0 : min;
            max = max === undefined ? 1 : max;
            this._seed = (seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
            return min + (this._seed / 233280) * (max - min);
        },

        numbers: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 1;
            var from = cfg.from || [];
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var continuity = cfg.continuity || 1;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var data = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = (from[i] || 0) + this.rand(min, max);
                if (this.rand() <= continuity) {
                    data.push(Math.round(dfactor * value) / dfactor);
                } else {
                    data.push(null);
                }
            }

            return data;
        },

        labels: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var min = cfg.min || 0;
            var max = cfg.max || 100;
            var count = cfg.count || 8;
            var step = (max - min) / count;
            var decimals = cfg.decimals || 8;
            var dfactor = Math.pow(10, decimals) || 0;
            var prefix = cfg.prefix || '';
            var values = [];
            var i;

            for (i = min; i < max; i += step) {
                values.push(prefix + Math.round(dfactor * i) / dfactor);
            }

            return values;
        },

        months: function(config) {
            var cfg = config || {};
            var count = cfg.count || 12;
            var section = cfg.section;
            var values = [];
            var i, value;

            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                value = MONTHS[Math.ceil(i) % 12];
                values.push(value.substring(0, section));
            }

            return values;
        },

        color: function(index) {
            return COLORS[index % COLORS.length];
        },

        transparentize: function(color, opacity) {
            var alpha = opacity === undefined ? 0.5 : 1 - opacity;
            return Color(color).alpha(alpha).rgbString();
        }
    };

    // DEPRECATED
    window.randomScalingFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Samples.utils.rand(-100, 100));
    };

    // INITIALIZATION

    Samples.utils.srand(Date.now());

    // Google Analytics
    /* eslint-disable */
    if (document.location.hostname.match(/^(www\.)?chartjs\.org$/)) {
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//web.archive.org/web/20210317115424/https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-28909194-3', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
    /* eslint-enable */

}(this));


}
/*
     FILE ARCHIVED ON 11:54:24 Mar 17, 2021 AND RETRIEVED FROM THE
     INTERNET ARCHIVE ON 15:38:56 Oct 13, 2021.
     JAVASCRIPT APPENDED BY WAYBACK MACHINE, COPYRIGHT INTERNET ARCHIVE.

     ALL OTHER CONTENT MAY ALSO BE PROTECTED BY COPYRIGHT (17 U.S.C.
     SECTION 108(a)(3)).
*/
/*
playback timings (ms):
  captures_list: 179.424
  exclusion.robots: 0.194
  exclusion.robots.policy: 0.177
  RedisCDXSource: 5.412
  esindex: 0.013
  LoadShardBlock: 142.04 (3)
  PetaboxLoader3.datanode: 1597.674 (4)
  CDXLines.iter: 22.523 (3)
  load_resource: 2495.07
  PetaboxLoader3.resolve: 980.408
*/
```

You can found the previous code in the following link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210317115424/https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30059414)

Comment: Why this code has references to Google Analytics?